# Filtering results from a subquery in MySql

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, correlated-subquery

I have a many to many user-sport relation and I'm getting a concatenated string of all sport names a user plays using a subquery. My structure looks like:

```
user
===============
| id |  name  |
---------------
| 1  |  Hugo  |
| 2  |  Paco  |
| 3  |  Luis  |
---------------

sport
=================
| id |   name   |
-----------------
| 1  | tennis   |
| 2  | football |
| 3  | handball |
-----------------

user_sport
======================
| user_id | sport_id |
----------------------
|    1    |    3     |
|    1    |    1     |
|    2    |    1     |
----------------------
```

how do I filter the results with users that play any sport from a list, for example getting all users who play tennis or handball.

I'm trying with this query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name,
COALESCE (
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(s.name SEPARATOR ', ')
  FROM sport AS s
  LEFT JOIN user_sport AS us ON us.sport_id = s.id
  WHERE us.user_id = u.id),'') AS sports
FROM user u
WHERE us.sport_id IN (1,3)
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY g.name
```

but it is not working because the where clause doesn't know the `user_sport` table. So, I have to create a new JOIN outside the subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to join with `user_sport` twice. Once to filter it to just the sports in the list, and the other time to get all the sports that the selected users play in.

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, GROUP_CONCAT(s.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS sports
FROM user AS u
JOIN user_sport AS us_filtered ON u.id = us_filtered.user_id
JOIN user_sport AS us_all ON u.id = us_all.user_id # all
JOIN sport AS s ON s.id = us_all.sport_id
WHERE us_filtered.sport_id IN (1, 3)
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.name
```